# iOS Trouble setting increment and decrement images for UIStepper

Tags: ios, uikit, uistepper

I'm able to set a background image fine with:

```
self.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
```

But if I do these:

```
self.setDecrementImage(image, for: .normal)
self.setIncrementImage(image, for: .normal)
```

The increment side changes the '+' into a blue square like so:

[image]

The decrement side is also actually a blue rectangle, except since it's the exact size of the minus symbol it still looks just like a minus symbol.  I can correct this by giving it a different size.

Anyone dealt with this?  Is there something special about the images for the increment/decrement sides as oppose to the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something special about the images

Sure, they are template images. If that isn't what you want, you need to call UIImage [`withRenderingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624153-withrenderingmode) to make a nontemplate image (`.alwaysOriginal`).

Comment: Elaborate working downloadable example from my book, here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch12p580stepper/ch25p853stepper/ViewController.swift